# Oauth Microsoft Exchange authentication

Tags: civimail, oauth

Has anyone set up CiviMail to use Oauth to connect to Microsoft Exchange? The CiviCRM documentation deviates from that provided by Microsoft. Also, you can't add the account are trying to set up, as you get this error:

*Application* is not configured as a multi-tenant application. Usage of the /common endpoint is not supported for such applications created after '10/15/2018'. Use a tenant-specific endpoint or configure the application to be multi-tenant.

Comment: Cross-ref to https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/2559, but posting here doesn't hurt either in case someone else has some solutions.

Comment: Editing <drupal root>\vendor\civicrm\civicrm-core\ext\oauth-client\providers\ms-exchange.dist.json to replace /common/ with /tenant-id/ enabled the application to be configured. Granting Graph API mail permissions in the application appeared to make it work.

Comment: @Demerit I'd forgotten about that thread! Thanks for referencing it. I'll go to it.

Answer (score 1):

In CiviCRM 5.59+, you can enter the tenant ID into the CiviCRM OAuth setup screen.